# Determinar si un variable contiene un entero o decimal en python

Tags: python

He intentado correr el código de abajo, pero por alguna razón apenas pide el año el código se para y no sigue, es como si no tuviera mas ordenes abajo, tampoco estoy seguro si la validación de `var1` se esta realizando bien.

```
import sys
print("Program that calculates if a year is leap or not")

var1=input("Enter the year you want to find out if it is leap or not: ")
if '.' in var1:
    print("Introduced a decimal number, the years can only be in whole number.")
    sys.exit

var2=int(var1)
if (var2%4)==0 and (var2%400)==0:
    print(var1,"it's a leap year, because it's a multiple of 4 or 400")
if (var2%100==0):
    print(var1," or it's a leap year, because it's not a multiple of 100")
```

Comment: Hola KDesing, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Debes traducir tu pregunta al español para que se adecúe a las normas del sitio.

Comment: Listo, ya hice la traducción, muchas gracias.

Comment: KDesing, creo que me has malinterpretado :) "Debes traducir tu pregunta al español ", es decir, traducir el cuerpo y el título de la pregunta al **español**, lo que has hecho ha sido traducir el código de la pregunta al inglés, el que uses literales de cadena o nombres de variables en ingles o español en el código es indiferente, lo importante es el contenido de la pregunta.

Comment: KDesing, ahora si está todo correcto :). En cuanto a tu problema, es en realidad solo un error tipográfico: **no llamas a `sys.exit` en ningún momento (faltan los paréntesis de llamada)**,  por lo que aunque se entre en el condicional, la ejecución del script no termina. Es decir, simplemente en vez de `sys.exit` debe ser `sys.exit()`. Un saludo.